# NSOperationQueue and disk I/O blocking

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have 3 `UITableViews` each when asked for a cell, async loads an image in a `NSOperation`. This is working perfectly until I insert cells, at which point cellForRow gets called and the operation is created and added to the queue.

The operations in the queue however are not processed for another few seconds, sometimes several seconds. I have another queue that is doing some image processing and saving the image to the disk; I suspect both these queues are competing for disk I/O, but I'm not sure. Ideally, when a image is processed, it should be loaded by the cell next. But it seems like the processing is done first and cells never get a chance to load, even though I experimented with the queue/thread priority. Can anyone with experience give me guidance?